# Can less than a 5 pack for Ubuntu Advantage Desktop be purchased?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I was wondering if there is anyway to get a single, or maybe 3 pack, no need for 5?

Comment: You can make you own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the minimum purchase is 5 units of Desktop support. At around $500, it is not a significant expenditure for a company that needs support and the guaranteed SLA that goes with it.

We expect home users, or smaller organizations that would rather not pay for support to ask questions on the forums - that is what the reference to AskUbuntu implies.  Our team monitors the site, and we all try to provide assistance to the Community in our respective areas of expertise.

So ask away, trying to make sure you attach the right tags to the inquiry - and even if you don't, a moderator will adjust them, it will only take a bit longer to route to the right folks.

Comment: It also compared well to what RH charged.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from the Ubuntu Advantage Site:

> Volume Purchasing.  Looking for business volume licensing? [Request a call](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/contact?utm_campaign=Canonical%2bStore).
>
> Interested in purchasing less than 5 Ubuntu Advantage subscriptions? Support is already free for you - visit [Ask Ubuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com/) to get in touch!

Now I don't know if this can be answered at Ask Ubuntu.  Maybe a Moderator would have more info on the subject matter, but I would recommend clicking on Request a Call above, and see if you can get an answer that way.

Comment: Volume purchasing is a standard term, referring to larger numbers, not smaller volumes.

Comment: @0xF2 I have been dealing with volume purchasing for over 15 years, so I know what the term means.  Its quoted from the site, and it was added as another way for the OP to get an answer to his question :)